# Steps to use routing in Ionic alpha v4

Tags: ionic4

Hello i made a demo app in ionic 3 with push and pop based navigation.In ionic 4 there is support for angular router so i need to navigate through pages using `router.navigate` events.I am trying to learn how angular router works in ionic.in In Ionic v4 we have `ion-router-outlet` which is new. I am not finding any documentation regarding how to use this element.If i use regular router(like `router-outlet`) it works good but i am not understanding which outlet tag should be used now? Can somebody tell me how can i achieve routing with `ion-router-outlet` in ionic v4?

Answer (score 1):

`ion-router-outlet` is the ionic's implementation of `router-outlet` with native transitions. You should use `ion-router-outlet` wherever you use `router-outlet`.

In short, use `ion-router-ooutlet` everywhere in ionic application